# Pandas - Filter multi-index by condition on all values within index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a dataframe with a multi-index similar to the following.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8),
             index=[list('AABBCCDD'),
                    ['M', 'F']*4])
data['Count'] = [1,2,15,17,8,12,11,20]
```

I would like to select all rows where 'Count' for *both* 'M' and 'F' inside a given outer level index is greater than 10. So for the example dataframe, all 'B' and 'D' rows should be selected, but none of the other rows. The only way I can think to do this is by looping through the outer index, but as loops in pandas are almost never the best way to do things I'm thinking there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`groupby` index then we using `filter` + `all` to get the all count more than the thresh

```
data.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x : x['Count'].gt(10).all())
Out[495]: 
            0  Count
B M  0.232856     15
  F  0.536026     17
D M  0.375064     11
  F  0.795447     20
```

Inspired by  Jpp using `isin`

```
s=data.Count.min(level=0).gt(10)
data.loc[data.index.get_level_values(0).isin(s[s].index)]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

Stacking and Unstacking with a level mask

```
data.unstack()[data.Count.gt(10).all(level=0)].stack()

            0  Count
B F  0.778883     17
  M  0.548054     15
D F  0.035073     20
  M  0.544838     11
```

### Option 2

Using `level` argument for `pandas.Series.all` and `pd.DataFrame.reindex`.
This avoids unstacking / stacking

```
mask = data.Count.gt(10).all(level=0)
data.reindex(mask.index[mask], level=0)

            0  Count
B M  0.548054     15
  F  0.778883     17
D M  0.544838     11
  F  0.035073     20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby.transform` for a vectorised solution:

```
res = data[data.groupby(data.index.get_level_values(0))['Count'].transform('min') > 10]

print(res)

#             0  Count
# B M  0.143501     15
#   F  0.964689     17
# D M  0.092362     11
#   F  0.981470     20
```